# Extracting a sentence containing a specific word from a longer text

Tags: java, strings, android

My goal is to return a specific sentence in a story that contains a given word. Returns `null` if the word is not in the story. I'm ok with returning the first occurrence if there are multiples. Is there a more efficient or cleaner way to do this?

```
public static String getSentence(String text, String word) {
    String sentence = "";
    if (text.toLowerCase().contains(word)) {
        if (text.contains(".")) {  //Are there sentences terminating in a period?
            int loc = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word);
            int a = loc;
            while (a >= 0) {
                if (text.charAt(a) == '.' || a == 0) {
                    sentence = text.substring(a,loc);
                    a = 0;
                }
                a--;
            }
            a = loc + word.length();
            while (a <= text.length()) {
                if (text.charAt(a) == '.' || a == text.length()) {
                    sentence += text.substring(loc,a+1);
                    a = text.length()+1;
                }
                a++;
            }
            return sentence;
        } else {
            return text;      //If no period, return full text
        }
    } else {
        return null;
    }
}
```

FYI - I'm implementing this in Android, so I don't believe I have access to Java 8.

Comment: `getSentence("abc. hello", "hello")` throws a `StringIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Is the code meant to deal with cases like this?

Comment: Good catch. It should.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There are a few things of interest with your solution. Firstly, it is a very literal implementation of the problem to solve, and I worry that it is too literal. For example, are you sure that sentences end with just a period `.`? Is it not a period and some whitespace? Is a URL like `example.com` two sentences?

The second issue I have is the blind trust you have in the inputs. You happily convert the input text to lower-case (too often, actually), but you do not convert the `word` to lower-case. If someone gives an upper-case word, you'll never find it.

I would prefer a more zen approach, using regular expressions... actually, just a split, and some Java 8 niceness.

```
private static final Pattern END_OF_SENTENCE = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s+");

public static String getSentence(String text, String word) {
    final String lcword = word.toLowerCase();
    return END_OF_SENTENCE.splitAsStream(text)
            .filter(s -> s.toLowerCase().contains(lcword))
            .findAny()
            .orElse(null);
}
```

Why is that better? Well, it streams the text in the form of sentences, and then finds the first match in a sentence. If there are no sentences, it matches the whole thing.

Note that the same principles can be used with a non-streaming approach. Split by sentences, then find the first match.

In an android environment, you could do:

```
private static final Pattern END_OF_SENTENCE = Pattern.compile("\\.\\s+");

public static String getSentence(String text, String word) {
    final String lcword = word.toLowerCase();
    for (String sentence : END_OF_SENTENCE.split(text)) {
        if (sentence.toLowerCase().contains(lcword)) {
            return sentence;
        }
    }
    return null;
}
```

Note that the results from the above code may, or may not include the terminating period. If the match is in the last sentence of a text, and that text ends with a period, then the period may be returned as part of the result. If there is a match in the middle of the text, then the period will not be included.

Comment: Wouldn't a regex like `"(?<=\\.)\\s+"` make it more sane w.r.t. to the period? It'd keep the period with its sentence and split on the following blanks.

Comment: This code looks so pretty - however I've discovered I'm not able to take advantage of Java 8 - I'm implementing this in Android.  So I can't use splitAsStream unfortunately.  I'll update the question to specify.

Comment: @Scott - updated with a non-streams version

Comment: Works great!  Thank you! I see that the s+ checks for a space afterwards - Is it too much to ask how do I add a check for a quote afterwards?  Also ! and ? as opposed to a period?

Comment: Got it using this: "[\\.!\\?][\\s\"]"

Comment: @Scott - Got a second to chat about that option [in the 2nd monitor chat room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/8595/the-2nd-monitor) - it needs a tweak?

Answer (score 2):

Toooooo complicated. And a bit inefficient, e.g., `text.toLowerCase()` gets computed three times. And you're doing

```
if (text.toLowerCase().contains(word)) {
    if (text.contains(".")) {  //Are there sentences terminating in a period?
        int loc = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word);
```

which could be simply

```
    if (text.contains(".")) {  //Are there sentences terminating in a period?
        int loc = text.toLowerCase().indexOf(word);
        if (loc == -1) {
            return null;
        }
```

Similarly, you should get rid of `text.contains(".")`. If there's none, a subsequent search will tell you.

---

I'd go for something like this:

- find (the first occurrence of) the `word`
- if not found, return `null`
- find the preceding `.`
- the sentence start is at the index following it (or 0 if not found)
- find the following `.`
- the sentence end is at the index of the dot (or `text.length()` if not found)
- return the sentence as substring

---

But this is still too complicated. Something like

```
Matcher m = Pattern.compile(
        "[^.]*" + Pattern.quote(word) + "[^.]*\\.?",
        Pattern.CASE_INSENSITIVE)
    .matcher(text);
return m.find() ? m.group().trim() : null;
```

does about the same as your code (untested). It looks for the first sequence of non-periods containing `word` (and extending as much as possible). The terminating period gets included, if any. As a sentence neither starts nor ends with blanks, the result gets trimmed.

The word gets quoted just in case it's not a word, but something like `$20`.

---

For the definition of sentence as something ending with a period *followed by blanks*, the regex would get rather convoluted, but it's possible as well. The pattern changes to something like

```
"([^.]|\\.+[^ .])*" + Pattern.quote(word) + "([^.]|\\.+[^ .])*\\.?"
```

employing an old trick: Accept a non-period (`[^.]`) or a period (or more of them) followed by a non-space-non-period (`\\.+[^. ]`). Any number of times (`*`).

Comment: This is returning matchFound=false. I'm so far not able to implement this solution.

Comment: @Scott Thanks, fixed by replacing `match` by `find`.